# Linq to XML Shows error "use of unassigned local variable.."?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Got confused why this is giving me error I think my code is correct

```
XElement outer = new XElement("Main");
XElement xsets;
XElement xsubsets;
foreach (DataRow nav_sets in GetNavigationSets().Rows)
{
    if (nav_sets["parent_id"].ToString() == null)
    {
        xsets = new XElement("Menu", nav_sets["name"].ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        if (int.Parse(nav_sets["id"].ToString()) == int.Parse(nav_sets["parent_id"].ToString()))
        {
            xsubsets = new XElement("SubMenu", nav_sets["name"].ToString());
            foreach (DataRow nav_menus in GetMenusInNavigationSetByNavigation(int.Parse(nav_sets["id"].ToString())).Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataRow menus in GetMenuById(int.Parse(nav_menus["menu_id"].ToString())).Rows)
                {
                    xsubsets.Add(new XElement("MenuItem", menus["name"].ToString()));
                }
            }
        }
        xsets.Add(xsubsets);
    }
    outer.Add(xsets);
}
outer.Save("main.xml");
cn.Close();
```

The error part shows in this line of code `xsets.Add(xsubsets);`

Errors:

> Error  1   Use of unassigned local variable 'xsets'
>      Error  2   Use of unassigned local variable 'xsubsets'

Got confused how can I get rid of this error.

Comment: Why exactly are you confused? The error message says exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it from

```
XElement xsets;
XElement xsubsets;
```

to

```
XElement xsets = null;
XElement xsubsets = null;
```

Comment: I tried that one already and it gives me error "Error 1 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments
"

Comment: Changed answer based on feedback from OP.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is that the compiler can't tell at compile time that the first case of the if statement is taken before the second is. Likewise in the second case, it doesn't know that before `xsubsets` is used, that the `if` statement will evaluate to true and create it.  While you may know this because of the format of the expected input, the compiler can't and gives you the error about the use of an unassigned variable.  By giving the variables an initial value (even `null`), you give them a value and the compiler is satisfied that you know what you're doing and haven't made a mistake.  Of course, if you do set them to `null` and then try to reference properties on them before they are used, you'll get a runtime exception but it isn't the compiler's job to worry about that if you've made sure that you satisfy its criteria.

Solve your compiler warnings by assigning an initial value of `null`.  My preference would be to go beyond that and check for `null` values before using them so that you can throw an exception with a more meaningful error message and log the exception condition.